# Delete all objects from NSMutableArray starting from index 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have `NSMutableArray` named `dishArray`. I have total 15 objects in this array.

I only want first three objects in array and delete the rest array.

Is there any way (other then looping) to delete?

I know using loop I can achieve it, but I am looking for alternate way. May be like `deleteArray From: To:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *array = ...;
if ([array count] > 3) {
    [array removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(3, [array count] - 3)];
}
```

Comment: +1: **for condition, else app will crash** & ***thanks, will accept after 10 mins...***

Answer (score 1):

Use the function removeObjectsInRange.

```
 if ([yourArray count] > 3)
 [yourArray removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(3, [yourArray count] - 3)];
```

Comment: And if the array only contains 1 object?

Answer (score 1):

Try with following code:

```
 if ([wholeArray count] > 3)    
    NSArray* finalArray = [wholeArray removeObjectsInRange(2, wholeArray.count-3)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSRange r;
    r.location = 0; // start position
    r.length = 3;  // end position

    [arr removeObjectsInRange:r];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[testArray removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(3, testArray.count-1)];
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in brief